# Bootstrap 4 - grid xs two columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have some problems with bootstrap 4, I would like to make 3 columns on bigger size, and 2 columns on xs.

I am not able to do this, because always on xs I have one column, what am I doing wrong? or I don't understand how the grid works?

https://jsfiddle.net/pgvdhcy4/

`<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            11111
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            3333
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            444
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            5555
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
            666
        </div>
    </div>`

Comment: You need to load in Jquery in order for bootstrap to work correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6) `col-xs-*` is now simply `col-*`..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            11111
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            3333
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            444
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            5555
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-6">
            666
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/6gFNUoXGoU

Comment: thank you I didn't understand the change, now I understand.

Comment: Thanks! This is still the case with Bootstrap v5.1, but screen breakpoints use xs as in `d-xs-block` which leave some room for confusion. A flexbox solution could also be applied with `container-fluid` and single `col`s following the same principle.

Comment: @OzgurO. - No, the `-xs` infix is not used anywhere in Bootstrap 5.x

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, the classes are named using the format {property}{sides}-{size} for xs and {property}{sides}-{breakpoint}-{size} for sm, md, lg, xl, and xxl. Adding xs achieves nothing.